# Trouble while compiling code - strncpy char* and string

Tags: c++

I have an issue with a class i have created. When i compiling this so occures error message. Its basically all about char* to string. Here is my class

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


class Stock //klassdekleration

{

private:
  char company[30];
  int shares;
  double share_val;
  double total_val;
  void set_tot() {total_val = shares * share_val;}

public:
  Stock();
  Stock(const char * co, int n = 0, double pr = 0.0);
  void acquire(const char * co, int n, double pr);
  void buy(int num,double price);
  void sell(int num, double price);
  void update(double price);
  void show();
  void compare( Stock );
  const char * returncompany();
  int returnshares();

};

#endif




// class function

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// constructor

Stock::Stock()
{
  cout << "pre constructor is called \n";
  strcpy(company, "namnlöst");
  shares = 0;
  share_val = 0;
  total_val = 0;
}

Stock::Stock(const char * co, int n, double pr)
{
  cout << " Constructor that use " << co << " is called \n";
  strcpy("company", co);
  company[29] = '\0';
  shares = n;
  share_val=pr;
  set_tot();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// andra metoddefintioner

void Stock::acquire(const char * co, int n, double pr)
{
  strcpy(company, co); //trunkera co om det behövs
  company[29]='\0';
  if (n<0)
    {
      cerr << "amount of shares cant be negative "
       << "share put to 0. \n";
      shares = 0;

    }
  else
    shares = n;
    share_val = pr;
    set_tot();
}

void Stock::buy(int num, double price)
{
  if (num < 0)
    {
      cerr << "Amount of bought shares cant be negative. "
       << "transaction cancelled. ";
    }
  else
    {
      shares += num;
      share_val = price;
      set_tot();
    }
}

void Stock::sell(int num, double price)
{
  if (num < 0)
    {
      cerr << "amount of sold shares cant be negative. "
       << "Transaction cancelled. ";
    }
  else if (num > shares)
    {
      cerr << "cant sell more shares than you posses"
       << "Transaction cancelled. ";
    }
  else
    {
      shares -= num;
      share_val = price;
      set_tot();
    }
}

  void Stock::update(double price)
  {
    share_val = price;
    set_tot();
  }

  void Stock::show()
  {
    cout << "Company: " << company
     << " Shares: " << shares << " \n"
     << " share value: $" << share_val
     << " Total value: $ " << total_val << " \n";
  }


 int Stock::returnshares()
 {
   return shares; 
 }

const char * Stock::returncompany()
{
  return company;
}



void Stock::compare(Stock stock2)
 {

   if (shares < stock2.returnshares())
     {
       cout << "Company" << stock2.returncompany() << "have higher share value than" << company;
     }
   else
     {
       cout << "Company" << company << "have higher share value than" << stock2.returncompany();
     }
 }
```

I get this error message.

```
In constructor ‘Stock::Stock(const char*, int, double)’:
Stock_class.cc:60:23: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   strcpy("company", co);
```

any idea how i can fix this issue ?

kind regards
Hampus hahne

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A hint though: Please read e.g. [this `std::strcpy` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy). And stop using `char` arrays or pointers for string, and start using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: #include <cstring>
#include <string.h> These are the same, except the first one is the one you should use in C++ code.

Comment: `char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );` This is how `strcpy` works.

Comment: And use string directly, don't write these, especially since you are not protesting against buffer overflows, this is very bad code.

Comment: @NutCracker the actual error has nothing to do with the title. OP probably has a `string foo("foo"); Stock stock(foo);` he isn'e showing, although his `strcpy` usage should be banned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems fairly obvious, you wrote

```
strcpy("company", co);
```

when you meant

```
strcpy(company, co);
```

Attention to detail is required.

Also

```
company[29]='\0';
```

is unnecessary because `strcpy` always adds a `'\0'` character, so you don't need to add one as well.

Answer (score 0):

i think in your code strcpy(company,co) will fix you problem.
usage of strcpy was not proper please follow below link for more details:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strcpy-in-c-cpp/